# mySQL statement to find nearly duplicate data with trailing slash

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am have a table named 'LINK_INFO' with URLs in a field called 'URL'. The problem is, many duplicates URLs exist EXCEPT some have used a trailing / to get around the unique field requirement.

Example:

http://www.yahoo.com
and
http://www.yahoo.com/

What is the statement I can use to select these cases of near duplicates, so I can delete one of them?  Many thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`TRIM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) to find all unique values;

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM url) url
FROM link_info
```

[SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6cc02/2).

To delete the duplicates right away, just do a delete join;

```
DELETE li1
FROM link_info li1
JOIN link_info li2
WHERE TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM li1.url) =
      TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM li2.url)
AND li1.id<li2.id
```

[Another SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90495/1).

Always back up your tables before running arbitrary SQL found on the net, even mine :)

EDIT: If your database machine is limited, you may want to do it using indexes and avoid loading more into memory than necessary;

```
-- remove all trailing slashes
UPDATE link_info 
SET url=TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM url);

-- create an index on the resulting strings (if there isn't already one)    
CREATE INDEX url_index ON link_info(url);

-- delete all duplicates
DELETE li1
FROM link_info li1
JOIN link_info li2
WHERE li1.url = li2.url
AND li1.id<li2.id;

-- drop the index if not needed anymore
DROP INDEX url_index ON link_info;
```

Yet another [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca64b/1).

Comment: Thanks.  Worked great in SQLfiddle, then backed up my database and tried running it on my server, and it brought down the whole VPS!  Is this a very resource intensive task to run?  The database is 50,000 rows.

Comment: @Jake 50k rows doesn't sound like much, but it would depend on the amount of memory in your VPS. Added an edit which should demand less resources.

Comment: Thanks so much for the code.  Tried the edited version and again, locked up my VPS.  It does not like my server!  I tested it on a smaller database and that one finally ran after 30 minutes on the same server.  Also the first code you gave worked exactly right on the test.  The second code you gave seems to deleted all trailing slashes, even from non duplicates, where the first code deletes only the duplicate entries, while leaving the unique URLs that wanted a trailing slash in the URL.  Is there a way I can run this to just find those duplicates, then copy that list and delete them later?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE link_info (
  url varchar(255));

INSERT INTO link_info VALUES
('http://www.yahoo.com/'),
('http://www.yahoo.com');

SELECT DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(url, LENGTH(url)) = '/' 
      THEN LEFT(url, LENGTH(url) -1)
    ELSE url
  END AS `url`
FROM link_info
```

**Result**

```
|                  URL |
------------------------
| http://www.yahoo.com |
```

### [See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2c119/1)

At this point you can insert this into a temp table, delete your parent and re-fill.