# mysql command works, but kills my server - alternate way to run?

Tags: mysql

I needed to find and delete near duplicate entries from my database that only differ by a trailing slash.  In other words, one row would have the URL "http://www.google.com" and another would have "http://www.google.com/"  I [posted this problem on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551809/mysql-statement-to-find-nearly-duplicate-data-with-trailing-slash) and a really helpful expert gave me [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14551949/1430996):

```
DELETE li1
FROM link_info li1
JOIN link_info li2
WHERE TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM li1.url) =
      TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM li2.url)
AND li1.id<li2.id
```

The code did exactly when I needed, except it uses up all my servers memory and kills my VPS every time.  Is there any alternative to run this in a less resource intensive or slower manner that will keep my server up?  I am running the command in phpmyadmin.  Thx!

Comment: Were you able to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

What about if you trim the trailing slashes with one statement:

```
UPDATE Link_Info
SET url=LEFT(url, LENGTH(url)-1) /*everything but the last character, which can only be a slash*/
WHERE url LIKE '%/';
```

*Then* run the clean-up script, but *without* the slash processing:

```
DELETE li1
FROM link_info li1
JOIN link_info li2
WHERE li1.url = li2.url
AND li1.id<li2.id
```

This way you can split up the processing. I don't know enough about MySql, but having a function in the join criteria (`TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM li1.url) = TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM li2.url)`) probably means that query can't benefit from any indexes, either.

Oh, and while you're at it, you might want to clean up any spaces too:

```
UPDATE Link_Info
SET url=LTRIM(RTRIM(url))
WHERE url LIKE '% %';
```

So I'd clean up spaces, then remove trailing slash, then de-dupe.

Comment: Thanks Jeromy.  The only issue I can think with that is, some of the URLs are not dupes but have a valid trailing slash that I don't want to delete....  For example, if there is a www.google.com/ and another www.google.com then I want to delete one of them.  But if there was only one www.google.com/  I don't want to touch that one.

Comment: Wouldn't it be ok to remove the trailing slash from "www.google.com/" so that it became "www.google.com"? Or do you *want* trailing slashes? Or do you only want to remove the entry with the trailing slash in the event that it's a duplicate of an entry without a trailing slash?

Comment: I would point out that your original query would not necessarily leave the record with or without the trailing slash--only the "first" record (the one with the lowest id).